# ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape () into shape()

Tags: python, numpy, append, valueerror

I am appending some arrays using a for loop as following :

```
nx, ny = lon.shape
for i in range(nx):
    j = np.argmin(lon[i,:])
    lon[i,:] = np.append(lon[i,j:],lon[i,:j])
    lat[i,:] = np.append(lat[i,j:],lat[i,:j])
    bathy[i,:] = np.append(bathy[i,j:],bathy[i,:j])
```

so far the loops works successfully because variable like "bathy" has only two dimensions (lon,lat). I want to append another variable called "temp" but this variable has (3D) three dimensions (time,lon,lat),  How can i do this ? Taking into account when I append such variable in the following way :

```
temp[i,:] = np.append(temp[i,j:],temp[i,:j])
```

I get the following error :

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1512000,) into shape (12,1331)
```

Comment: Reread the `np.append` dics - the whole thing!

Comment: May you clarify more please !

Comment: If you don't understand where the `(1512000,)` shaped array comes from, you aren't using `np.append` right.  What's the shape of `temp`?  `np.append` is a thin, and many ways misleading, cover for `np.concatenate`.  Pay attention to what it is actually doing.  Don't assume; test.

Comment: temp shape is (12, 1050, 1440). I am using np.append, because I want to make each row start at the index of the min longitude of that row. If temp has only 2 dimensions (lon,lat) (1050,1440), the loop works with me. But, I want to repeat such step over the third dimension which is time (12).  (1512000,) comes from (1050*1440) (lon*lat)

Comment: `np.append`, without an axis parameter **flattens** the arrays!  Didn't you see that in docs?  Or saw it but didn't understand its relevance?  `np.append` is best for adding a single number of a 1d array.  For almost anything else it has too many pitfalls for careless novice users.  If I had my way, the function would be deleted.